# How to do an absolute sorting of columns in a matrix (numpy)

Tags: python, sorting, matrix, numpy-ndarray

So i have a matrix:

```
    a = np.array([[7,-1,0,5],
                  [2,5.2,4,2],
                  [3,-2,1,4]])
```

which i would like to sort by absolute value ascending column . I used np.sort(abs(a)) and sorted(a,key=abs), sorted is probably the right one but do not know how to use it for columns. I wish to get

```
    a = np.array([[2,-1,0,2],
                  [3,-2,1,4],
                  [7,5.2,4,5]])
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try [argsort](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.argsort.html#numpy-argsort) on `axis=0` then [take_along_axis](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.take_along_axis.html#numpy-take-along-axis) to apply the order to `a`:

```py
import numpy as np

a = np.array([[7, -1, 0, 5],
              [2, 5.2, 4, 2],
              [3, -2, 1, 4]])

s = np.argsort(abs(a), axis=0)
a = np.take_along_axis(a, s, axis=0)
print(a)
```

`a`:

```
[[ 2.  -1.   0.   2. ]
 [ 3.  -2.   1.   4. ]
 [ 7.   5.2  4.   5. ]]
```